# Python error - "ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'"

Tags: python, linux

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omermazig/.virtualenvs/fixi/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/omermazig/.virtualenvs/fixi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/omermazig/.virtualenvs/fixi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/home/omermazig/.virtualenvs/fixi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
  File "/home/omermazig/.virtualenvs/fixi/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from distutils import dist, sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'
```

When I run anything with python. This specifically is for trying to run "pip freeze". What to do?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-distutils

Comment: sudo apt-get worked for me ! thanks

Answer (score 53):

try it

```
sudo apt install python3-distutils
```

Comment: it fixed the ImportError for me (Ubuntu 16.04 inside a virtualenv with python3.6).

Comment: there's no such thing as Ubuntu inside a virtualenv. You must mean virtualenv with python3.6 running on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: "python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.7.3-1ubuntu1)"  did not solve problem (which happens in a virtualenv, not system python)

Answer (score 24):

My case was when I upgraded Ubuntu 18 -> 19. 
So it reinstalled python and what I needed to do is:

1. remove old virtual environment
2. create a new one
3. install requirements via pip into it

Comment: yep, i just upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 and the same happened to me.

Comment: @Comm4nd0 Same here. But I could not create a requirements.txt from the old one either! Should be done before the Ubuntu upgrade!

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this problem after installing Python 3.8 on Ubuntu (I have version 16.04)

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:     Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
```

1. **Reproduce the error**

Just try to import `distutils`

```
$ python3 -c "from distutils import sysconfig"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)

$ sudo apt install python3-distutils          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-distutils
```

The package `python3-distutils` cannot be found

```
$ sudo apt install python3-distutils          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-distutils
```

2. **list available distutils**

What helped was to list all `distutil` packages using a regexp

```
$ apt list *distutils*
Listing... Done
python-distutils-extra/xenial,xenial 2.39-1 all
python-stsci.distutils/xenial,xenial 0.3.7-4 all
python3-distutils-extra/xenial,xenial 2.39-1 all
python3-stsci.distutils/xenial,xenial 0.3.7-4 all
python3.7-distutils/xenial,xenial 3.7.8-1+xenial1 all
python3.8-distutils/xenial,xenial 3.8.3-1+xenial1 all
python3.9-distutils/xenial,xenial 3.9.0~b4-1+xenial1 all
```

3. **Install the correct distutils package**

For my Python 3.8 I picked `python3.8-distutils` and it worked

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y python3.8-distutils
```

Comment: But if `python-3.7` remains installed in the system, it will still be broken, and cannot import the missing `distutils/dist.py` file :-(

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install -y python3.8-distutils worked.

Answer (score 13):

Since I run into this issue everytime I update my ubuntu version every six months, then stumble on the exact same SO result, here is my solution.

If the other solutions listed here don't work (installing `python3-distutils`), it might be because of different python versions between the system and the virtualenv.

The easy solution is to destroy your virtualenv, then recreate it from scratch.

Comment: Worked for me! Also had to change the python version in the `[requires]` section of my Pipfile.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I've just got this issue in a virtual environment installed 2 years ago, using python3.7

Running **pip3** or **python3.7 -c "from distutils import dist, sysconfig"** from the venv, I got the error *ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'*

Using system python 3.9, this error disappers.

I solved copying the /usr/lib/python3.9/distutils into the python3.7 virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

Take a loot at this (similar problem):
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5367

Possible fix:

- Download Python source from https://www.python.org/
- Decompress the source code
- Install the following dependencies:

  sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev (needed to compile Python)
- and install:

sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev (needed by Pip to make SSL requests)

- Compile and install Python:

/configure

make

make install

- Python 3.6 with Pip should be installed.

Full credit to jonbesga.

Comment: It's not ideal to compile things from source in Ubuntu, regarding updates and distribution integration.